# How to create DRYer Constructors

Tags: java, list, constructor

Is there any way I can make any of the following constructors less repetitive? I.e. only using one constructor or not having multiple 'topping.add' calls? My aim is to have a pizza which can have either 1, 2 or 3 different toppings

```
private PizzaBase base;
List<PizzaTopping> toppings = new ArrayList<PizzaTopping>();

public Pizza(PizzaBase base, PizzaTopping topping) //Constructor for pizza with 1 topping
{
    setBase (base);
    toppings.add(topping);
}

public Pizza(PizzaBase base, PizzaTopping topping, PizzaTopping topping2) //Constructor for pizza with 2 toppings
{
    setBase (base);
    toppings.add(topping);
    toppings.add(topping2);
}

public Pizza(PizzaBase base, PizzaTopping topping, PizzaTopping topping2, PizzaTopping topping3) //Constructor for pizza with 3 toppings
{
    setBase (base);
    toppings.add(topping);
    toppings.add(topping2);
    toppings.add(topping3);

}
```

Originally I was thinking of using a for loop to add the provided toppings to the list, but I wasn't sure how I could iterate through the values given by the constructor

Comment: You're looking for varargs.

Comment: Couldn't the constructor just take `List<PizzaTopping>` as a parameter?

Comment: @SLaks: it will allow more than 3 toppings though, that might not be wanted. At the very least he should call the base constructor and add the extra topping.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about codereview rather than codefixing. Please refer to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) and we'll gladly help you there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using varargs you can use as many toppings as you want and dont worry about it inside the constructor, you treat it as a list

```
private PizzaBase base;
List<PizzaTopping> toppings = new ArrayList<PizzaTopping>();

public Pizza(PizzaBase base, PizzaTopping... toppings) //Constructor for pizza with 1 topping
{
    setBase (base);
    for(PizzaTopping topping : topings)
        toppings.add(topping);
}
```

Comment: This loses one benefit of 3 constructors: people can add more toppings than intended. If you're exposing this as an interface, how will you enforce this? Documentation is not a good substitute for hardcoded boundaries imo.

Comment: Agreed with you, in which case it'll be better to place 3 overloading constructors as it'll be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

Use a constructor that takes no PizzaToppings. Make a method addToppings and you can call the method as needed to add any number of toppings.

Or, have a constructor that takes a List of PizzaToppings.

Comment: If you take this approach, you should also make `addTopping` return `this`. That way you could do `new Pizza(PizzaBase.Thin).addTopping(PizzaTopping.Olives).addTopping(PizzaTopping.Corn).addTopping(PizzaTopping.Mushrooms)` instead of breaking it to multiple statements.

Comment: @IdanArye: good point. This seems like a good case for the Decorator pattern, to be honest.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Decorator is good when you want to change the behaviour of (what appears to be)the object. Toppings don't really change the behavior of the pizza - they act more like info added to the pizza. Using the decorator pattern here will not really add any needed flexibility - it'll only make the syntax for creating pizzas with toppings uglier and the extraction of the topping data more cumbersome. Though to be honest - doing a lot of work to make the interface ugly and cumbersome without adding any real value *is* the Java way...

Answer (score 1):

I would have an array of the toppings be one of the parameters of the constructor.

```
public Pizza(PizzaBase base, PizzaTopping[] topping) {
    setBase(base);
    for (int i = 0; i < topping.length; i++)
    toppings.add(topping[i]);
}
```

If you wanted to limit the number of toppings able to be put on the pizza you could do it with an `if` statement:

```
if (topping.length > 3) { /*do the for loop*/ }
else /*Write an error message*/
```

Comment: Arrays are ugly, at least use varargs so the caller doesn't have to explicitly create a new array and fill it.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely look at the Builder pattern it's a classic in software design.

[Builder on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern